# Is there a way to run a python file from its directory

Tags: python, directory

Is there a pythonic way to run another python file from its directory

Say I have two files

main/one/test.py

main/two/other.py

What code would I have to put in test.py in order to run other.py at other.py's directory

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

os.system('python3 ./other.py')
```

Comment: The file path is wrong. You will need '../two/other.py'

Answer (score 0):

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from two import other
```

This only works if you are **running from current directory**, i.e. using `python test.py` and not `python main/one/test.py`.
`../` means the parent of the current directory, e.g. if you are in `main/one`, `../` is `main`. So here, line 2 appends `main` to PYTHONPATH, meaning that it now adds the folder `main` to the list of directories to import modules from. This means that you can import/import from any folder or file inside `main`.
Then, line 3 imports `main/two/other.py`, causing any code inside that file to be run.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.